# Paypal AdaptiveAccounts service and CreateAccount operation-Getting 'Authentication failed' error

Tags: java, web-services, soap, paypal

I am trying to make a SOAP webservice call (AdaptiveAccounts Service and CreateAccount operation). On invocation of webservice, I am getting the Authentication error (Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.)
I am using the API credentials as provided on Sandbox account creation, but not able to figure out the exact issue. Please let me know if anything wrong with the request.
Kindly suggest a solution for this.
Here is my request and response XML as following.

```
========================REQUEST  XML=========================
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:urn="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xmlns:urn1="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <urn:RequesterCredentials>
            <urn1:Credentials>
                <urn1:Username>SandboxUsername</urn1:Username>
                <urn1:Password>SandboxPassword</urn1:Password>
                <urn1:Signature>AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31ADYp5gFqA3XsQwuoGCUc3wgZHitU
                </urn1:Signature>
            </urn1:Credentials>
        </urn:RequesterCredentials>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/services">
        <ns2:CreateAccountRequest>
            <requestEnvelope>
                <errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage>
            </requestEnvelope>
            <accountType>PERSONAL</accountType>
            <emailAddress>testing1-2039@paypal.com</emailAddress>
            <name>
                <firstName>Srikanth</firstName>
                <lastName>Rao</lastName>
            </name>
            <dateOfBirth>1968-01-01Z</dateOfBirth>
            <address>
                <line1>1968 Ape Way</line1>
                <line2>Apt 123</line2>
                <city>Austin</city>
                <state>TX</state>
                <postalCode>78750</postalCode>
                <countryCode>US</countryCode>
            </address>
            <contactPhoneNumber>888-555-1212</contactPhoneNumber>
            <currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>
            <citizenshipCountryCode>US</citizenshipCountryCode>
            <preferredLanguageCode>en_US</preferredLanguageCode>
            <notificationURL>http://...</notificationURL>
            <registrationType>WEB</registrationType>
            <createAccountWebOptions>
                <returnUrl />
            </createAccountWebOptions>
        </ns2:CreateAccountRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
=========================================================================

=============RESPONSE XML============================================
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header />
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault xmlns:axis2ns245141="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <faultcode>axis2ns245141:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns4:FaultMessage xmlns:ns4="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/common"
                    xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/aa">
                    <responseEnvelope>
                        <timestamp>2015-04-15T11:14:16.838-07:00</timestamp>
                        <ack>Failure</ack>
                        <correlationId>8b0f4547f0ea8</correlationId>
                        <build>13599725</build>
                    </responseEnvelope>
                    <error>
                        <errorId>520003</errorId>
                        <domain>PLATFORM</domain>
                        <subdomain>Application</subdomain>
                        <severity>Error</severity>
                        <category>Application</category>
                        <message>Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.
                        </message>
                    </error>
                </ns4:FaultMessage>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
===================================================================
```

Comment: what url are you making the SOAP request to? I remember that the sandbox credentials could only be used on the sandbox server, which has a different url to production.

Comment: I forgot to mention the target url. Here it is below.
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/CreateAccount

yes, the credentials that are mentioned in the request, are from Sandbox account.

Comment: any suggestions please.